# Is it possible to use together @Id (from JPA) and @Generated (from Hibernate) annotations for a field which is part of a composite primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key

We have an entity which is using a composite primary key (we are using `@IdClass` approach because we want to use our custom ID generator). This composite key is defined like this:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class BasePK implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private Instant createdAt;
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof BasePK)) {
            return false;
        }
        BasePK that = (BasePK) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) && Objects.equals(createdAt, that.createdAt);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, createdAt);
    }

}
```

And the entity class looks like this:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(BasePK.class)
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Identifiable <String> {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GenericGenerator(name = "ulid-generator", strategy = "com.example.common.jpa.ULIDIdentifier")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ulid-generator")
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 26)
    private String id;
    
    @Id
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Instant createdAt;
    
    // ETC.

}
```

The SQL definition is like these (notice that we want to generate the `CREATED_AT` in the database side just by using a default current UCT time):

```sql
MY_TABLE {
    key ID           String(26) not null;
    key CREATED_AT   Timestamp not null default CURRENT_UTCTIMESTAMP;
    // ETC.
}
```

We are aware that using timestamp is not good idea in primary keys and that it could also very easily be generated in application side by using Hibernate `@CreatedDate` annotation, but the requirements we have received is that **this timestamp has to be generated in database side**.

So we tried the approach of using the Hibernate annotation `@Generated` in order to tell Hibernate to exclude the `createdAt` from the generated SQL, but we noticed that that field is still there in the Hibernate generated SQL: `Hibernate: insert into MY_TABLE (ID, OTHER_FIELDS, CREATED_AT) values (?, ?, ?)` and that is, of course, making the inserting to fail, because the statement has an extra value that shifts everything resulting in inserting the wrong type and value in the wrong fields.

Is there any way to achieve what we are trying (even though it might be a bad design from the beginning, but for now is not in our hands to change those requirements).

Comment: This is not possible. But why is the timestamp part of the key? UUID is already unique

Comment: Perhaps the duplication of fields with `@IdClass` causes this. You don't need `@IdClass` to generate composite primary keys. Multiple `@Id` already handle this

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the reason timestamp is part of the primary key is because they want to create different rows with the same ID (ULID) and different createdAt (timestamp) when a row changes, so there is no update of rows, only creating new rows that are essentially the same, but different version. This is inefficient, but not a problem in certain DB providers.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer are you sure about that? How then are you going to use the composite key in a spring repository: `public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, BasePK` I believe the shadowing `@IdClass` is required.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer According to the JPA spec you must have a IdClass.

Comment: Hibernate supports GeneratedValue in composite PKs from Hibernate 6. Are you using Spring Boot 3?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, we are not using Hibernate 6, although `@GenerateValue` is available in 5.X too, as you can see in the example, we are using it in the `id` part of the composite key to apply our custom `ULID` generator.

Comment: Yes, it's available but doesn't work with composite keys

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It is actually working, as you can see in my example, the `id` field (which is part of a composite key) is correctly working with `@GenerateValue`. There is no problem in that at all.